# Spring Boot: efficiently get data from REST API

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that (among other things) gets some data from a third party JSON API (secured with OAuth), processes the result and presents it to the user. The application receives approx. 1 request each second.
Unfortunately this process is very slow at the moment (and in many cases even ends with a 503 error) and I am looking for some idea to improve the implementation. (by the way: the third party API itself does not seem to be the bottleneck as a instance of my app running on my local machine using the exact same API response very fast at the same time that the deploy instance takes very long).

For the API call I use the Apache HTTP library - or more specifically the Async HTTP Client:

```
this.httpClientAsync = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider) //for forward proxy
                    .build();
```

And the actual call to the API is this:

```
updateToken(); //get or update OAuth Token
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
Future<HttpResponse> f = this.httpClientAsync.execute(httpget, callback);
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to improve the implementation?
To be honest, I don't even have an idea where the bottleneck is at the moment. Any idea on how to find out about that?

Thanks for your hints!

One more thing/update: 
the Spring Controller looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/api_data")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Map>> getAPIData() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Map>> res = new DeferredResult<>();

  triggerAPICall(new FutureCallback() {
    public void completed(Object o) {
      (...)
      res.setResult(...);
    }
    (...)
  }

  return res;
}
```

Furthermore, I was originally not using the async version of the HTTP client, but the blocking version. This then even slowed down the rest of the application...

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you are providing. I would go back to the synchronous call for now, just to simplify the code and isolate the problem; in any case, 1 request per second is a very low rate and different requests get processed on different threads anyway. Try benchmarking the response time of the request, just to be sure the problem isn't there. If you are still stuck, try posting a minimal functioning example

Comment: Thanks for this hint. The API calls in deed take a very long time - and the run time also seems to increase with the up-time of the Spring service: right after start-up the response time is 1-2 sec, but after a while it climbs to 10+ sec. Between the Spring service and the API we have a forward proxy in place - my guess is now that this might be the cause of the issue...

Comment: as said by @Pedro , i don't think problem comes from the code since from your local machine it works fine. Maybe you have a proxy, or something on the machine where you deployed the app. I suggest a test using cURL from both you local machine and your production instance just to be sure this is not coming from the code, or any jvm parameters.

Comment: This is a long shot, but is there any chance you are using spring hateoas on the API side? Cause I had a similar problem a few months ago only to find out there was a memory leak bug in the version of spring hateoas I was using